# d3js json pie chart

Tags: json, d3.js

I am trying to create a piechart for some data I have in a JSON file, however I keep getting an error and I am not sure why.
My JSON file is like this:

```
{"data":[
    {"ap": [
        {"floorratio": [
            {"floor":"Basement", "ratio": 0.20},
            {"floor":"Ground", "ratio": 0.20},
            {"floor":"First Floor", "ratio": 0.15},
            {"floor":"Second Floor", "ratio": 0.20},
            {"floor":"Third Floor", "ratio": 0.25}
        ]}
    ]},
    {"ap": [
        {"floorratio": [
            {"floor":"Basement", "ratio": 0.10},
            {"floor":"Ground", "ratio": 0.30},
            {"floor":"First Floor", "ratio": 0.10},
            {"floor":"Second Floor", "ratio": 0.15},
            {"floor":"Third Floor", "ratio": 0.35}
        ]}
    ]}
]}
```

and my HTML code is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pie Chart Test</title>
    <script src="d3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.arc path {
  stroke: #fff;
}
</style>

<body>


<script>
var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(0);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function (d) {
    return d.data[0].ap[0].floorratio[0].ratio;
});

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

d3.json("APCategories.json", function (data) {

    var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
        .data(pie(function (d) { return d.data[0].ap[0].floorratio[0]}))
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "arc");

    g.append("path")
        .attr("d", arc)
        .style("fill", function (d) {
        return color[d.data[0].ap[0].floorratio[0].floor];
    });

    g.append("text")
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
    })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function (d) {
        return d.data[0].ap[0].floorratio[0].floor;
    });

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I keep getting the error when I inspect the element that i.map is not a function. Am I reading the data into the code incorrectly? Any help would be appreciated.

edit: I am currently only trying to load the first ap, the json file will be much bigger and I will be creating a pie chart that changes so that it represents each ap.floorratio.
So for now, only the data from the first floorratio array needs to go into the pie chart.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what part of the data you want to make into a pie chart? Just the first "ap"? Or a pie chart for each one?

Comment: @sharoz, I want to make just one, but it will change which I will add later. For now, I am just trying to load the first ap.

Comment: @sharoz, clarified in the edit. Let me know if you need to know more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working version.

```
var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(0);

// defines wedge size
var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function (d) { return d.ratio; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

d3.json("APCategories.json", function(error, data) {
  node = data.data[0].ap[0].floorratio;  // <------ here

  var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie(node))
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

  g.append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.floor); });

  g.append("text")
      .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function (d) { return d.data.floor; });
});
```

The [0] after floorratio wasn't necessary.

http://bl.ocks.org/steveharoz/0638d230c133da1de385

Comment: thanks, I thought I might have to initialise the data into a variable like the csv versions but wasn't quite sure how to with json.

Comment: Hey I was wondering what the correct syntax would be if I wanted to load the whole data set for an animated pie chart.

From what I understand node = data.data[0].ap[0].floorratio; loads the first set of ratios and if i change it to
 node = data.data[1].ap[0].floorratio;

 it will load the second set of ratios. 
What would I have to do to make it so I can do something like this: 
node = data.data[i].ap[0].floorratio;?